# How to call an external program and process its output?

Tags: go

I am trying to call an external command (e.g., `seq 10`) and take its output, process the output then print out the processed results. But the following code does not work. Could you please let me know how to make it work?

```
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "os"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("seq", "10")
    stdin := bufio.NewReader(cmd.Stdout)
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }

    for {
        line, err := stdin.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err == io.EOF {
            if len(line) == 0 { break }
        } else {
            if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
            line = line[:(len(line)-1)]
        }
        os.Stdout.Write(line)
        os.Stdout.Write([]byte{'\n'})
    }
}
```

```
$ $ go run main.go 
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:15:30: cannot use cmd.Stdout (type io.Writer) as type io.Reader in argument to bufio.NewReader:
    io.Writer does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)
```

EDIT: I also tried this. But it also has error. Could anybody show me a working example.

```
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "os"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("seq", "10")
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    stdin := bufio.NewReader(stdout)
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }

    for {
        line, err := stdin.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err == io.EOF {
            if len(line) == 0 { break }
        } else {
            if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
            line = line[:(len(line)-1)]
        }
        os.Stdout.Write(line)
        os.Stdout.Write([]byte{'\n'})
    }
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdoutPipe

Comment: The example in https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Command should be useful. Try looking there first.

Comment: @PaSTE The example there is not clear. Would you show the complete code on how to use ReadBytes to process the external command's output?

Comment: @user1424739: if you want to use `bufio.Reader`, use `StdoutPipe` from the first comment, which also has a complete example.

Comment: @JimB I can not make it work. Could you show me a working example using ReadBytes?

Comment: @Dani See the above comment as well.

Comment: @user1424739: The example uses `cmd.Start()`, but you're calling `Run()`, which can't work, because stdout is blocked. If you want to use `Run()` and process the output after then give the command a buffer and not a pipe.

Answer (score 4):

Another method (and a cleaner one) is to use `bufio.Scanner` which handles `\n` (or any other delimiter) automatically. Another advantage is that this method doesn't have race issues (been there, done that):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("seq", "10")
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Start() failed with %s\n", err)
    }

    stdin := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    for stdin.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(stdin.Text())
    }
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

`stdin.Scan()` returns false on `EOF`, which is given once the process exits. `cmd.Wait()` will close `StdoutPipe`, and you can read `err.(exec.ExitError).ExitCode()` to get the exit code (if exited non-zero).

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/ba387a/how_to_choose_between_bufionewscanner_and/. It seems that `Scan()` can not work with arbitrarily long lines and it doesn't return the deliminator, which I will need to distinguish when I need to read the last line. Do I understant it correctly? If both cases are so, then it is not appropriate for my application.

Comment: According to that post, Scanner can scan (by default) up to 64k lines. Also, you can always append the newline byte, so that's not much of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pipe the standard out to the reader using `.StdoutPipe()`, you also need to use `exec.Command(..).Start()` to read incrementally (`.Run()` waits for the process to exit).
Here is the working code:

```
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("seq", "10")
    cmdStdOut, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    cmdStdErr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    defer cmdStdOut.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("command failed with %s\n", err)
    }
    stdoutReader := bufio.NewReader(cmdStdOut)
    stderrReader := bufio.NewReader(cmdStdErr)
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }
    // Read stdout
    for {
        line, err := stdoutReader.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err == io.EOF {
            if len(line) == 0 {
                break
            }
        } else {
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            line = line[:(len(line) - 1)]
        }
        os.Stdout.Write(line)
        os.Stdout.Write([]byte{'\n'})
    }
    // Read stderr
    for {
        line, err := stderrReader.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err == io.EOF {
            if len(line) == 0 {
                break
            }
        } else {
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            line = line[:(len(line) - 1)]
        }
        os.Stderr.Write(line)
        os.Stderr.Write([]byte{'\n'})
    }
    cmd.Wait()
    fmt.Println(cmd.ProcessState.ExitCode())
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How to catch the exit status of the external program?

Comment: You can `Wait()` and read the `ProcessState`. I updated the sample.

Comment: How to print the stderr of the external program to the stderr of the go program?

Comment: Same way but using `StderrPipe()` instead.